# TextBox doesn't fire Invalidated event

Tags: c#, textbox, invalidation

Why TextBox doesn't raise Invalidated event when it's caret appear and disappear and when its text be changed ?

```
class Form1
{
    TextBox t = new TextBox();

    public Form1()
    {
        t.Invalidated += delegate(object sender,InvalidatedEventArgs e)
        {
            //this event doesn't be fired,why ?
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you setup Validation Rules?

Comment: I realy don't know what do talk about , I ment that when I change the text of t above,'Invalidated' doesn't be raised.
Thanks